# Load the Ajax Result in the main (parent) page's div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In the main page, there is a `<div>` with id - `"search_result"` to show all the search result. The search result was loaded via ajax call. The result (sub-page) is directly put into the `div`.

In the sub-page, I can catch the click event and do another `ajax` call to receive the result. I want to load the result back to the main page's `div` `"search_result"`. I cannot.

Here is the partial html of **main page**.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>search</title>
    ......
  </head>
  <body>
    ......
    <div id="search_results"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the sub-page content that is loaded into the `"search_results"` `div`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#update_op").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        // Ajax here
        $.ajax({
            type:   "POST",
            url:    link,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data) {
                $("#search_results").html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;  // for good measure
    });
});
</script>


<div class="div_table">
  <div id="item_row_4" class="div_row">
    <div class="div_cell">
      <a id="update_op" class="update_op op" href="http://abc/bk/v/show-update/id/4">update</a>&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`$("#search_results").html(data);` This line is not loaded the result I receive.

**Solution: the dataType change to html and it works.**

Comment: Perhaps you want to change to `dataType: "html"` or `dataType: "text"`? It doesn't make much sense to append a JSON object to a div.

Comment: Looks like it was my mistake. I change it to html. Seems working now.

Answer (score 2):

click event for runtime dom loaded elements has to be written in this way

```
$("#update_op").on('click',function(event){
    e.preventDefault(); // return false
    $.ajax({
        url: "url to fetch result",
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#search_results").html(data); // this would change the data, you could use append(), prepend() etc. you would have to process data to display with css if needed
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and here is my solution:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#update_op").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        // Ajax here
        $.ajax({
                type:   "POST",
                url:    link,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                           location.reload();
                       }
        });
        return false; //for good measure
     });
});
</script>
```

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why are you using "dataType" JSON, you're not sending a json so, you shouldn't put that code.

Here an example with a file name "probando.php". It works good for me.

```
<body> 
<div id="search_results"></div>
<br /><br />
<div class="div_table">
    <div id="item_row_4" class="div_row">
        <div class="div_cell">
             <a id="update_op" class="update_op op" href="probando.php">update</a>&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#update_op").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        // Ajax here
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response){
                $("#search_results").html(response);
            }
        });
     });
});
</script>
```

And "probando.php" code:

```
<?php
    echo "Hola Mundo!";
?>
```